# Air density equation in stratosphere

Tags: gravity

Does the density equation for air on Earth change in the outer atmospheres? I am generating a model for the Red Bull Stratos jump and am trying calculate a precise air density function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Barometric formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula) is the answer if we assume we deal with ideal gas - as far as I know it's good approximation of what is happening in real atmosphere.

Comment: The barometric formula is a fit to the real conditions in each layer of the atmosphere - rather than a gas model. That's probably why it works